# Correctly starting multithreading c # execution

Tags: c#, multithreading

Tell me what is the correct way to start the multithreaded execution of the method, I need to start the execution of the method (program) in 100 threads.
For example, I need to take proxies from the list and check for a 200 response.

How to properly run the program in 100 threads?

```
//Array Threads
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            arrThread[j] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(new Worck().SearchUrls));
            arrThread[j].IsBackground = true;
            arrThread[j].Start();
        }

//Array Tasks
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            arrTask[j] = new Task(new Worck().SearchUrls);
            arrTask[j].Start();
        }

//Task
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {
                new Task(() => new Worck().SearchUrls()).Start();
            }
        });

//Parallel
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Parallel.For(1, 100, new Worck().SearchUrls());
        });
```

Comment: [`Thread.Start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.start?view=net-5.0)?  i strongly recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). as well as learning how to use search engines and how to read manuals in general.

Comment: starting 100 threads sounds like a terrible idea, especially for something that is checking URLs, which is inherently *not a CPU-bound operation*

Comment: Isn't using Task.Run on a Parallel.For redundant and useless?

Comment: @OlivierRogier: Not if the calling thread is a UI thread.

Comment: @OlivierRogier: `Parallel.For` splits its work among multiple thread pool threads, and *also* enlists its current thread as one of the "worker" threads until the parallel work is done. So if the current thread is a UI thread, then the UI is frozen until the work is done.

Comment: You can also use Rx and do `Observable.Range(0, 100).SelectMany(x => Observable.Start(() => new Worck().SearchUrls)).Subscribe(x => /* each result */));`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to properly run the program in 100 threads?

I generally recommend using the highest-level API that is available.

In this case, `Parallel.For` is the highest-level API. The `Parallel` type splits its work into `Task`s, which are distributed among threads in the thread pool.

Manually creating `Thread` objects should be extremely rare; these days it's only necessary if you're doing things like COM interop. [Manually creating `Task` objects via the `Task` constructor should **never** be done](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

> For example, I need to take proxies from the list and check for a 200 response.

In this case, the question is wrong. You don't need 100 threads to do that. Or any explicit threads, for that matter.

Since the operation is I/O-bound, what you want is an asynchronous solution. First, write a properly-asynchronous `SearchUrlsAsync` (e.g., by making asynchronous network calls). Then, you can start all the asynchronous operations and then asynchronously wait for them all to complete:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(_ => new Worck().SearchUrlsAsync()).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```